# how to show all photos using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to collect all photos in pictures directory to show them in GridView, so tried with two ways.
1_ without using AsyncTask: this way worked very well but it has a problem which is that the app freezes for seconds to get all photos in specified directory and it's sub directories.
2_using AsyncTask: this way doesn't get any images and the list of images is always empty, I know that I should use Asynctask for processes that take mush time to processed and I don't know what I missed when using AsyncTask.
what I want is to find a way to collect all photos using AsyncTask with app freezing and thanks in advance.

```
public static class ImagesFragment extends Fragment {
                static List<Image> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
                GridViewRecyclerAdapter gridViewRecyclerAdapter;
                GridView gridView;
                Spinner spinner;
                public static File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    
                @Override
                public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //                imagesList = loadImageData(file);
                    gridViewRecyclerAdapter = new GridViewRecyclerAdapter(imagesList, getContext());
                }
    
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_images, container, false);
                    spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            switch (position){
                                case 0:
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    
                        }
                    });
                    gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
                    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewRecyclerAdapter);
                    return view;
                }
    
                public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
                    // Raw height and width of image
                    final int height = options.outHeight;
                    final int width = options.outWidth;
                    int inSampleSize = 1;
                    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
                        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                            inSampleSize *= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    return inSampleSize;
                }
    
                public static List<Image> loadImageData(File file) {
                    String fileType;
                    String extension;
                    if(file.isDirectory()){
                        File[] files = file.listFiles();
                        for(File file1: files){
                            if(file1.isDirectory())
                                loadImageData(file1);
                            else{
                                extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file1.getPath());
                                if (extension != null) {
                                    fileType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                                    if(fileType != null)
                                        if(fileType.contains("image")){
                                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 500, 500);
                                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file1.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    //                                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight())
                                            imagesList.add(new Image(bitmap, file1.getName(), file1.getPath()));
    
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getPath());
                        if (extension != null) {
                            fileType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                            if(fileType != null)
                                if(fileType.contains("image")){
                                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 500, 500);
                                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
                                    imagesList.add(new Image(bitmap, file.getName(), file.getPath()));
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    return imagesList;
                }
            }
    
            public static class GridViewRecyclerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                List<Image> imageList;
                Context context;
                static int position;
    
                public GridViewRecyclerAdapter(List<Image> imageList, Context context){
                    this.imageList = imageList;
                    this.context = context;
                }
    
                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return imageList.size();
                }
    
                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return imageList.get(position);
                }
    
                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }
    
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder viewHolder;
                    if(convertView == null){
                        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.images_item, parent, false);
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
                        viewHolder.imageView.setTag(imageList.get(position).path);
                        viewHolder.textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
                        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                    }
                    else
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    new LoadImageAsyncTask().execute(ImagesFragment.file.getAbsolutePath());
                    viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(imageList.get(position).bitmap);
                    viewHolder.textView.setText(imageList.get(position).title);
                    GridViewRecyclerAdapter.position = position;
                    return convertView;
                }
    
                public static class ViewHolder{
                    ImageView imageView;
                    TextView textView;
                }
    
                static class LoadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Image>> {
                    @Override
                    protected List<Image> doInBackground(String... objects) {
                        ImagesFragment.imagesList = ImagesFragment.loadImageData(new File(objects[0]));
                        return ImagesFragment.imagesList;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I would have a rethink of what you want to do. `AsyncTask` was actually deprecated a while ago and isn't recommended for use anymore.

Comment: i know it's deprecated but it would help in my case if correctly implemented